# XAML not getting namespace

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I've properly changed the namespaces of my xaml page, but somehow VS not getting the namespace. I tried to do it in the way others have suggested, still getting this error,
"The name "LayoutAwarePage" does not exist in the namespace "using:Inventory.Common".

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
x:Name="pageRoot"
x:Class="Inventory.MainPage"
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Inventory"
xmlns:common="using:Inventory.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
```

My Main page extends from LayoutAwarePage, this xaml is inside the Common Folder. And the project name is Inventory.

Comment: Is `LayoutAwarePage` in `Inventory.Common` namespace? Does it build or simply report an error? I've seen the XAML editor often report IntelliSense errors that are wrong and the project would still build.